# Gesture recognizers with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, uipangesturerecognizer

I have an app with some card swiping functionality. It seems that on small devices the gesture recognizer covers the correct area, but on iPhone 6 (and after applying a bunch of constraints) I can only swipe my cards from a small portion of them. I tried removing and adding the gesture recognizer to my views, I also tried re-creating the recognizer thinking that maybe once the views have been painted it would take the correct bounds,... but no success so far.

Any considerations in regards to this?

Comment: I am sorry... what are you asking?

Comment: if there is anything I need to keep in mind when working with a UIGestureRecognizer, when the view I am applying this recognizer to is going to be dynamically resized on bigger devices.